# jQuery error: $(...).modal is not a function

Tags: jquery, asp.net, bootstrap-modal

I use this code to call a modal and pass some data:

```
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
    if (e.CommandName.Equals("editRecord"))
    {
        GridViewRow gvrow = GridView1.Rows[index];
        HfUpdateID.Value = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(gvrow.Cells[1].Text).ToString();
        txtNameUpdate.Text = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(gvrow.Cells[2].Text);
        /*
            txtEmailIDUpdate.Text = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(gvrow.Cells[3].Text);
            txtAddressUpdate.Text = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(gvrow.Cells[4].Text);
            txtContactUpdate.Text = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(gvrow.Cells[5].Text);
        */
        lblResult.Visible = false;
        System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
        sb.Append(@"<script type='text/javascript'>");
        sb.Append("$('#myModal').modal('show');");
        sb.Append(@"</script>");
        ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "EditModalScript", sb.ToString(), false);
    }
}
```

I'm using this version of JQuery and Bootstrap:

```
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

But I have this problem in the console. The modal won't open.

```
VM2312:1 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).modal is not a function
at <anonymous>:1:15
at Sys._ScriptLoader._loadScriptsInternal (MicrosoftAjaxWebForms.js:6)
at Sys._ScriptLoader._nextSession (MicrosoftAjaxWebForms.js:6)
at Sys._ScriptLoader._loadScriptsInternal (MicrosoftAjaxWebForms.js:6)
at Sys._ScriptLoader._nextSession (MicrosoftAjaxWebForms.js:6)
at Sys._ScriptLoader.loadScripts (MicrosoftAjaxWebForms.js:6)
at Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager._onFormSubmitCompleted (MicrosoftAjaxWebForms.js:6)
at Array.<anonymous> (MicrosoftAjax.js:6)
at MicrosoftAjax.js:6
at Sys.Net.WebRequest.completed (MicrosoftAjax.js:6)
```

Comment: where do u call the script? before or after u call the the modal? make sure u call the  jquery and bootstrap b4 running the modal pop up function

Comment: @Se0ng11 But i have the <scritpts> tags inside the head,the scripts i put above

Comment: but looking at the error message, it seem that it not recognize bootstrap modal, is your `#myModal` is in the page? if not, u need to be put somewhere in master page or the page itself so that it able to know where to call, the layout should exactly the same as what bootstrap page is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to add your bootstrap.min.js script just before the end  and jquery scripts in header